error message using offCanvas element of bootstrap
I want to make this react component using bootstraps Offcanvas-component. It's an example from the React-bootstrap webpage.
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch
      </Button>

      <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
          <Offcanvas.Title>Offcanvas</Offcanvas.Title>
        </Offcanvas.Header>
        <Offcanvas.Body>
          Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you
          have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
        </Offcanvas.Body>
      </Offcanvas>
    </>
  );
}

export default Example;

But I got this error:
**error message using row element of bootstrap: TS2786: Row cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type ReactNode is not a valid JSX element. Type undefined is not assignable to type Element | null**
I tried importing all the packages again and installing bootstrap again. I even checked my package.json file but the problem isn't solved. I have the problem with all the bootstrap components

I'm not sure the code you shared is where the issue actually is. this sandbox is effectively the same code and seems to work

Is there a way that is can clearify this more so somebody can help?

If you can manage to make a sandbox that reproduces your issue then that would be ideal. It is possible your JSX configuration for whatever it is you are using to transpile JSX  is set to transpile it into native elements rather than react elements. I suggest more clarification based on that. The sandbox I shared uses react-scripts so it handles all of that but if you are using something else it might be worth sharing what that is.

I have sort of created the same situation in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/offcanvas-zcv2dr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A11%2C1 I have copy pasted my package.json. You can see the error message at the Offcanvas element.

Can you make that sandbox public or unlisted?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/offcanvas-zcv2dr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A11%2C1 Is this good?
